# ''ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer'' when connecting from school

Tags: ssh

I tried to connect to a debian server from my school wifi which is blocking the default port 22 so I switched to 443, but even then I get an error when trying to connect.

Here is the debug:

```
$ ssh -v user@host -p 443
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to host [host] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su] or [unix.se] instead of here. When you do that, you should explain why you think the server is going to accept an ssh connection on port 443.

Comment: Yes, some firewalls only allow normal HTTP/HTTPS to talk. I think nowadays they also realized that some users open SSH port to 443 and so that they can connect to remote server and eventually do tunneling-over-ssh to bypass the firewall. The HTTPS server shows nothing initially when a client is connected, but SSH server does shows its program name and OS version. So the firewall vender can use some pattern recognition to block your connection to SSH servers by sending TCP reset packet to both ends.